# Anything annotate on class field that can override global date format for @ModelAttribute in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

After I set global date format in `application.properties` like this

```
spring.mvc.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

The `@ModelAttribute` won't use the date format set by `@DateTimeFormat` on the class field. Is there any annotation can annotate on the class field and override the global date format?

Thanks

Comment: Could you create a non web small sample, without Spring Boot? I suspect this is in a way related to how plain Spring does the conversion. I suspect the global one takes precedence over the annotation one. If that is the case this is kind-of a bug/issue in Spring itself, if not it has to do with ordering of formatters in Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum But ModelAttribute can't be used in non web project,right?It's part of SpringMVC.

Comment: The problem isn't related to `@ModelAttribute` but binding I suspect, and especially the other in which things are consulted or registered (if that is of importance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this was an acknowledged bug, fixed in Spring Framework [5.2.1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/23893) and [5.1.11](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23896), November 2019.

I'm currently stuck with Spring Boot 1.5 (Spring 4.3.x) so am using a workaround of declaring the date request parameter as a String and performing the validation/conversion in the controller implementation using SimpleDateFormat.

```
public List<...> getByBillingDate(           
    @ApiParam("Billing Date in format yyyy-MM-dd") 
    @RequestParam(value="billingDate", required=true) String strBillingDate) {
    try {
        Date billingDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(strBillingDate);
        // ... call business logic with billingDate
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for billingDate parameter. Required format is yyyy-MM-dd", e);
    }
}
```